# Python: pseudo try before actually try and finding exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I know I'm not clear on this thing but I couldn't be more specific in the title. Consider the following code:

```
try:
    print "Try this out"
    a = int("Blah blah")
except:
    print "I got the exception"
```

The output of this code is-

```
Try this out
I got the exception
```

What I want the python to do is to check if it might raise an exception  in the try: block first and then execute it. Else, just execute the except: block. Is it possible to do such a thing without nesting the multiple try-except blocks.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing? That goes against the Python philosophy of [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html).

Comment: This question or purpose isn't very clear. How would you do it with nested blocks? Would you want the 'pseudo-run' to have side effects? Can you first check a condition first before executing the code that raise an exception? That sounds more like what you're trying to do.

Comment: Python is completely dynamically typed. I think you're referring to languages such as Java where functions can be labeled with the `throws SomeExceptionType` at the end of their function declaration. Python is not like this. You receive the exceptions during runtime and cannot determine if it will (or, really, even can) throw.

Comment: Actually, it's based on a project where I'm working on a database entry where I need to clear database if a new entry comes up (try:), else just continue with further execution of code. So if I clear my database and then discover the exception, I can't return back to the previous state of database.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, because you get an exception during execution. But you can do like this:

```
try:
    a = int("Blah blah")
    print "Try this out"
except:
    print "I got the exception"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try statement prints up as no error happens in printing it ,but as soon as it tries to execute `a`, gets an error so `except` executes.

Try this way to catch the exception properly:

```
try:
    a = int("Blah blah")
    print ("Try this out")

except:
    print ("I got the exception")
```